# Generalizing "partition into odd parts=partition into distinct parts"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

The number of [partitions into distinct parts](http://oeis.org/A000009) is known to agree with the [number of partitions with odd parts](http://oeis.org/A000009). For instance, this follows from
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+q^k)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-q^{2n-1}}. \tag1$$
I like to emphasis that there is also a bijection proving this assertion.

Assume $p$ is an odd prime. One can extend (and **prove algebraically**) equation (1) to
the following generalization
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}(1+q^{pk-m})
=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{\substack{j=1\\ 2j\neq p+1}}^p\frac1{1-q^{2pn-2j+1}}.\tag2$$
For example, if $p=3$ then
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+q^{3k-1})(1+q^{3k-2})
=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(1-q^{6n-1})(1-q^{6n-5})}.$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is a combinatorial (bijective, etc) proof of (2) known in the literature? If not, can you furnish one?

Comment: If you are using the bijection that goes through the binary expansion of the multiplicity of each odd part, then that same bijection (restricted to the appropriate set of partitions) proves your general identity.

Comment: The $p=3$ example you give is known as Schur's partition identity.  I would be surprised if the general bijection you request in *not* in Igor Pak's [survey](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/psurvey.pdf).

Comment: @BrianHopkins: I just finished browsing Pak's survey. I couldn't locate anything (explicit) there regarding $p>3$.

Comment: Related OEIS entries: $p = 3$ [A003105](https://oeis.org/A003105), $p = 5$ [A096938](https://oeis.org/A096938), $p = 7$ [A097793](https://oeis.org/A097793).  Those include references to sequences corresponding to the left-hand side of (2) for composite $p$.